# Fixing an IP conflict

Tags: networking, ip

I tried to static box on our network. Win Server 2003 tells me, intermittently, that I have an IP conflict. I have the box that originally had this IP sitting next to me, unplugged and off. I moved the new box to a different IP, and the first IP, that Windows said was in use, is not ping-able. NMAP shows nothing. Any ideas how to find it?

> Starting Nmap 4.11 (
>   http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at
>   2009-08-11 12:28 EDT All 1680 scanned
>   ports on 192.168.11.46 are filtered
>
> Nmap finished: 1 IP address (1 host
>   up) scanned in 1713.025 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the event log, usually there is an [entry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727689%28WS.10%29.aspx) with the hardware address of the offending machine.  Once you have the hardware address simply track that down using your switches or your inventory database.

If you are doing any bonding/teaming/fault tolerance with the nics on your server you'll want to check that too.  I have seen issues where the teaming tools cause the system to conflict with itself.  Check that your network drivers are up-to-date and everything is configured correctly.

Comment: I picked up the mac from the event log, then decoded that into a manufacturer. That was enough to figure out what it was.

Answer (score 1):

MAC address of the other machine should show in the IP conflict error in Event Viewer.  If you don't have all your machines MACs documented then look up the MAC addresses vender to narrow your search.

Is this conflict constant or once every few days or weeks?

Edit: Zoredache beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the static address that you are using the the DHCP pool range?  Another possibility is that you have rogue access point/DHCP server that is plugged in wrong/misconfigured.  I have run in to both of these this summer on my campus.